# Cmd - Unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: batch-file, cmd, parentheses

I have written an rpg game. But it alway says :

```
Unbalanced parenthesis.
```

This is the code :

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
::MAX SETTING
::PLS REFER TO FILES\DIALOGUE\.
set diamaxna=6
set diamaxnr=5
set diamaxsa=2

::MAIN SETTING
:SETTING
cls
echo Set HP of your character.
set /p myhp=
echo Set HP of your enemy.
set /p enhp=
if "%myhp%"=="" set myhp=0
if "%enhp%"=="" set enhp=0
echo Choose difficulty. 1 is the easiest and 3 is the most difficult.
choice /c 123 /n /m "[1,2,3]"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" set enatk=25
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="2" set enatk=50
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3" set enatk=70
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :EOF
cls

::HP CHECK (EN & MY)
:battle.check
if %enhp% LEQ 0 goto battle.win
if %myhp% LEQ 0 goto battle.lose

::BATTLEVAR
:sp.bool.check
set /a sp_bool=%random% >nul
if %sp_bool% GTR 250 goto sp.bool.check
if %sp_bool% GTR 100 set special=0
if %sp_bool% LEQ 100 set special=1

::ENEMY DIALOGUE GET AND CHECK
:endia.get
set /a encurdia=%random%*%diamaxnr%/32768+1 >nul
set /p enlongcurdia=<"%~dp0Files\Dialogue\NR\%encurdia%.txt"

:dia.check
if "%special%"=="1" (
set /a curdia=%random%*%diamaxsa%/32768+1 >nul
) ELSE (
set /a curdia=%random%*%diamaxna%/32768+1 >nul
)

:dia.get
if "%special%"=="1" (
set /p longcurdia=<"%~dp0Files\Dialogue\SA\%curdia%.txt"
) ELSE (
set /p longcurdia=<"%~dp0Files\Dialogue\NA\%curdia%.txt"
)

:mydam.get
if "%special%"=="1" (
set /a mydam=60+(%random%*120/32768+1) >nul
) ELSE (
set /a mydam=40+(%random%*30/32768+1) >nul
)

:endam.get
set /a endam=%enatk%+(%random%*10/32768+1) >nul

::BATTLE+DIALOGUE
set /a enhp=enhp-mydam
set /a myhp=myhp-endam
echo %longcurdia%%mydam%. Enemy remain HP %enhp%.
echo %enlongcurdia%%endam%. Your remain HP %myhp%.
goto battle.check

::WIN V.S. LOSE
:battle.win
echo You win!
choice /c YN /n /m "Restart?"
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto SETTING
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto END

:battle.lose
echo You lose!
choice /c YN /n /m "Restart?"
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto SETTING
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto END

:END
echo Press any button to exit......
pause >nul
```

I can't solve it. I read this code for many times but I still can't find the problem.
Actually, what does

> Unbalanced Parenthesis

mean?

Any help will be appreciated. ^.^

Comment: Where ? WHere can i find (()?

Comment: Do you mean the tag `mydam.get`?

Comment: No, I'm saying that's what "unbalanced parenthesis" means; either too many or too few closing `)`, or some syntax problem preventing a closing `)` from being recognized. I don't see any obvious instance of it in your code, though I've never written batch files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:mydam.get
if "%special%"=="1" (
set /a mydam=60+(%random%*120/32768+1^) 
) ELSE (
set /a mydam=40+(%random%*30/32768+1^) 
)
```

The caret (`^`) "escapes" the `)`, telling `CMD` that it's a part of the calculation, not of the `IF` statement.

- the `>nul` on your `set /a` statements is superfluous.
- try `set /a var=%random% %% %maxvalue% + 1` to roll 1..maxvalue
- why not use

  set "dialogue=%~dp0Files\Dialogue"

  then "%dialogue%...."

Comment: +1, Another option is to enclose the assignment within quotes: `set /a "mydam=60+(%random%*120/32768+1)"`. Or simply remove the parentheses, since they are not needed due to order of operations: `set /a mydam=60+%random%*120/32768+1`. I much prefer your modulo suggestion over any of the others.

Comment: I don't like the caret ^ job. @dbenham solution is more elegant. Quotes prevent a lot of errors in CMD.